# Embedding Lua: how to programatically save a script to a folder, how to compile a script?

Tags: c++, lua

I am embedding Lua in a C++ application, and I am using luaL_dofile to load a script

However, I cannot seem to find documentation on the functions to use to:

1. Compile a script (and save byte stream to a specified folder)
2. Save a script to a specified folder

last but not the least, when I use luaL_dofile to load a script into the Lua engine, if the loaded script has a line that loads a module for example:

```
require 'strict'
```

which directory would the script.lua (or its compiled version) be loaded from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look up [luaL_loadfile](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#luaL_loadfile) and [lua_dump](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#lua_dump). See also `test/luac.lua`.

Answer (score 1):

For the question about where Lua looks for modules require'd: It depends on `package.path` and `package.cpath` variables, which can be influenced by the environment variables `LUA_PATH` and `LUA_CPATH`.